# Chroot seems to be missing some progs/libs. What's necessary to get default commandline behaviour?

Tags: linux, bash, chroot

I've set up a chrooted environment using [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny) tutorial. But the commandline isn't displayed correctly. Instead of the usual `user@hostname:/home/user#` it displays `-bash-4.1$`. What programs are needed to get the "default" linux commandline look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the PS[1-4] environment variables to change the layout of your bash prompt. Check out http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/ for some examples.

Comment: How do I set these variables for every login?

Comment: If you want the prompt set for every login PS1 is what you're looking for. PS1 is the environment variable that defines the primary prompt string. It is set in ~/.bashrc. Add the following to .bashrc: **export PS1="\u@\h:\w\a\$"** (by convention # is reserved for root, a non-administrative user should use $ or >).