# Chrooted user does not start in his home directory and does not load his bash_profiles

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, chroot

If the users logs in, he starts in / of the chroot (Which is /var/jail on the real machine). I would like him to start in his home-dir. Also, he seems not to load any of his profile-files (.bash.rc etc). I followed [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny) tutorial to create the chroot environment. This is what my /etc/passwd looks like:

```
test:x:1004:1008:,,,:/var/jail/home/test:/bin/bash
```

this is what my /var/jail/etc/passwd file looks like:

```
test:x:1004:1008:,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

I also found out that, if I remove

```
Match User test
    ChrootDirectory /var/jail
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

from my /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the user starts in his correct home-folder and with his bash-settings loaded. However, he is able to leave the chroot-environment if I remove that part. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/438386/chroot-seems-to-be-missing-some-progs-libs-whats-necessary-to-get-default-comm) question I asked before is somewhat related, since I think the wrong look of the commandline is caused from the not loaded profile-files. So any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of  **ls -la /var/jail** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration is correct except for a small detail: the home directory in `/etc/passwd` should not contain the chroot path part. Change it to:

```
test:x:1004:1008:,,,:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

restart `sshd` and try again.

From `man sshd_config`:

> ChrootDirectory
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.  **After the
>   chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home
>   directory.**

That is, first `sshd` executes `chroot` (in our case `chroot /var/jail`), and then `sshd` changes the directory to the user's homedir (in our case `cd /home/test` - in a chrooted environment `cd /var/jail/home/test` wouldn't work).

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu (since the tutorial you mention is for Debian) you may want to create a file named `/var/jail/etc/debian_chroot` with contents "chroot", this will appear in the user prompt in parentheses like this: `(chroot)test@servername:~$`.

(I've duplicated your configuration on my Ubuntu 12.04 and it has worked after removing `/var/jail` from user test's entry in `/etc/passwd`.)

Comment: I found out that ftp and sftp did not work properly if you just write `/home/test` as home directory. I had to write `/home/test/./` to fix the problem with ftp/sftp! Now everything works fine.